# What obfuscator is used?

Tags: deobfuscation, .net, c#

In version 3.7.3.7 I was able to modify some parts of the code using dnSpy. The language is C#. But in the new(next) version, I did not succeed and I guess the code is obfuscated. De4dot did not help. Thanks for any help!

Link for *untouched* 3.7.4.1 exe and *cracked* 3.7.3.7 exe:

https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ1x8LXZjkm0YjbRzdfMqwAkkLsUu8RM42qV

Answer (score 0):

You could try every deobfuscator on this list, until one works
https://github.com/NotPrab/.NET-Deobfuscator